# Combine multiple user actions within one SQL string

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a SQL query that will show me all contacts who have clicked on all 3 of these email Job IDs:

```
Select CM.* from [US_B2B_TRADE_Contacts113020] CM join [_Click] C On CM.[Contact ID] = C.subscriberkey
where C.JobID IN ('13498391') and where C.JobID IN ('15194352') and where C.JobID IN ('15194353') and (C.URL like '%hurtigruten%')
```

Comment: You need to include some information about the actual problem that you're having.  You say you're "trying to write a SQL query" ...... it looks like you've written one .... but then what?  You're getting an error message?  You're not seeing the results you expect?  You will probably also need to show an example of the data in the tables that you are querying from, since no-one is going to inherently just understand the data that you are trying to query.  Also, please tag which specific RDBMS you are using, as query syntax can differ between different systems

Comment: Thanks Craig, sorry for not including more info. I am receiving an error "Errors: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'." I am basically wanting to pull a record who has clicked within these three job IDs. The SQL string would pull in the contact.

Comment: Read the documentation instead of trying to make up your own syntax

Comment: Actually, I didn't even notice it the first time ..... you don't need "and where" every time.  After the first "where", you just need "and" in between the criteria

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You've obviously misunderstood how you should structure your WHERE clause.

Instead of

```
Select CM.*
from [US_B2B_TRADE_Contacts113020] CM
join [_Click] C On CM.[Contact ID] = C.subscriberkey
where C.JobID IN ( '13498391' )
and
where C.JobID IN ( '15194352' )
and
where C.JobID IN ( '15194353' )
and
(C.URL like '%hurtigruten%')
```

it should just be

```
Select CM.*
from [US_B2B_TRADE_Contacts113020] CM
join [_Click] C On CM.[Contact ID] = C.subscriberkey
where C.JobID IN ( '13498391' )
and
C.JobID IN ( '15194352' )
and
C.JobID IN ( '15194353' )
and
(C.URL like '%hurtigruten%')
```

The keyword "WHERE" only needs to be specified once, at the beginning of the clause, even if there are multiple criteria that you're applying to the statement

Comment: Craig, thank you so much, I am new to SQL so appreciate you taking the time to help.

Comment: No problems.  Can you upvote my answer if you're happy with it?

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to write a SQL query that will show me all contacts who have clicked on all 3 of these email Job IDs.

You need some way to combine information from different rows in order to answer this question.  Why?  One row does not have multiple `jobId`s.

The idea is to filter down to all contacts that have at least one of the job ids.  Then check that those have all three:

```
select CM.[Contact ID]
from [US_B2B_TRADE_Contacts113020] CM join
     [_Click] C
     On CM.[Contact ID] = C.subscriberkey
where C.JobID IN ('13498391', '15194352', '15194353') and
      C.URL like '%hurtigruten%'
group by CM.[Contact ID]
having count(distinct c.JobId) = 3;
```

Notes:

- `IN` is much more convenient then a bunch of `OR` conditions.
- If `JobId` is really a number, then drop the single quotes.  Do not mix data types.
- If `JobId` cannot have duplicates for a given contact, then use `count(*) = 3` rather than `count(distinct)`.